# Why does "Terminal" retain focus / stay in the foreground when I open other apps, and how do I prevent or change that?

Tags: terminal, finder, applications

When I have "Terminal" in the foreground and open another application, the new application opens in the background (rather than the foreground).
This is rather annoying, as I always need to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the application after opening it.

This is not limited to the "open" command in Terminal - it also is occurring when I click the icon in the dock to open the application, or open the application using Spotlight (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

Why is this happening, and how do I change it so that applications open in the foreground and context switches from Terminal to the newly opened application?

Note: this is a relatively new Mac, and a colleague who has also received a new Mac is also 'suffering' the same problem.

Comment: Does this issue happen with just Terminal? I.e. Could you be in another app, say `Music.app` and then opening another app from the dock say `Notes.app`... and then `Music.app` stays in the foreground with `Notes.app` opening in the background? If it's just affecting `Terminal.app` then I think there's some sort of preference plist setting that's keeping `Terminal.app` active in the foreground... but I don't know where to look for that setting unfortunately

Comment: Also when opening applications from terminal, you aren't using the `-g` or `-j` option when running the `open` command in terminal right? I.e. Don't run `open -a [application name.app] -g` command, but instead run `open -a [application name.app]`. I don't think this is your issue though, since you say it also happens with other opening methods, so I still think it has something to do with a plist file related to UI/Mission Control/Terminal/Global preferences, but I couldn't say which one.

Comment: @AVelj - yes, it only happens when Terminal is in focus. Just had another colleague discover that the issue occurs for them too. Possibly an OSX12 issue, maybe?
It's not to do with opening things *from* the terminal, merely opening something when the terminal is in focus.
The 'plist' sounds like a good line of investigation - however I can't fathom what value(s) I might play with.

Comment: @techchiken, i'm not sure which plist either... There's an app called `Prefs Editor` by Thomas Tempelmann, that may help. The app essentially does what the `defaults writes/read` commands do, but presented as a GUI app. So you could load any plist in the app and investigate from there? Not sure if it will allow you to modify system plists requiring sudo but certainly any plists in your user directory, i.e. terminal's settings specific to your user.

Comment: Also as an extra troubleshooting measure, have you tried creating a new user account and doing the same steps (using terminal and then open another app) in the other user account? If the issue doesn't happen in the other user account, it's most likely to be a plist setting specific to your user account that is causing the issue!

Comment: I can't see anything obvious using the "Prefs Editor" application. I also just tried creating a new 'Standard' user and the same thing occurs.

Comment: Very strange! Tried reaching out to Apple (if its a new Mac under warranty?)

Comment: It is very strange! I have posted on the Mac forums, but two other colleagues are experiencing the same thing with their [also brand new] Macs. I suspect it's a thing with macOS 12. I found a solution though - I've switched to iTerm ... no more issues. Not exactly a solution to this specific question, but a solution to my problem.

Comment: I've been experiencing this issue too on Monterey 12.6.3. Steps to repro: Open terminal, type `open .` to open a finder window in the current directory, notice the finder window is below Terminal. I've tried deleting the Terminal plist to no resolve.

Answer (score 3):

The com.apple.terminal.plist is located in ~/library/preferences and deleting it resolved the issue in my case, where I was able to switch to the finder app but keystrokes were still being applied to terminal.

**However, please note removing the plist also removed my custom terminal profiles** so please go to Terminal>Preferences>Profile and click export on the gear cog if you wish to save your customizations.  The problem with Terminal retaining functional focus may return if the profile is reimported, but I didn't get a chance to test this.

If removing the whole plist is not an option, try

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse No
```

and restart Terminal.